# Shell script stops automatically after around 1 minute

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wrote this very ugly shell script that, at one point, worked perfectly. Now it works for a minute or two and then exits. I know its very ugly but it worked so I never changed it. Could anyone tell me what's going wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting..."
timestamphour=`date +%F_%H`
mkdir /Some/Directory1
mkdir /Some/Directory2
mkdir /Some/Directory3
mkdir /Some/Directory4
mkdir /Some/Directory5
mkdir /Some/Directory6
mkdir /Some/Directory7
mkdir /Some/Directory8
mkdir /Some/Directory9

#This could be done in one step
mkdir /Some/Directory1/$timestamphour
mkdir /Some/Directory2/$timestamphour
mkdir /Some/Directory3/$timestamphour
mkdir /Some/Directory4/$timestamphour
mkdir /Some/Directory5/$timestamphour
mkdir /Some/Directory6/$timestamphour
mkdir /Some/Directory7/$timestamphour
mkdir /Some/Directory8/$timestamphour
mkdir /Some/Directory9/$timestamphour

for i in {1..3600}
do
#timestampmin=`date +%F_%H-%M`
timestampsec=`date +%F_%H-%M-%S`
sudo curl -o /Some/Directory1/$timestamphour/$timestampsec.jpg http://some.address.at.some:port1/jpg/image.jpg &
sudo curl -o /Some/Directory2/$timestamphour/$timestampsec.jpg http://some.address.at.some:port2/jpg/image.jpg &
sudo curl -o /Some/Directory3/$timestamphour/$timestampsec.jpg http://some.address.at.some:port3/jpg/image.jpg &
sudo curl -o /Some/Directory4/$timestamphour/$timestampsec.jpg http://some.address.at.some:port4/jpg/image.jpg &
sudo curl -o /Some/Directory5/$timestamphour/$timestampsec.jpg http://some.address.at.some:port5/jpg/image.jpg &
sudo curl -o /Some/Directory6/$timestamphour/$timestampsec.jpg http://some.address.at.some:port6/jpg/image.jpg &
sudo curl -o /Some/Directory7/$timestamphour/$timestampsec.jpg http://some.address.at.some:port7/jpg/image.jpg &
sudo curl -o /Some/Directory8/$timestamphour/$timestampsec.jpg http://some.address.at.some:port8/jpg/image.jpg &
sudo curl -o /Some/Directory9/$timestamphour/$timestampsec.jpg http://some.address.at.some:port9/jpg/image.jpg &
sleep 1
done
```

Comment: If you run it with `bash -x` does that show you anything of import?

Comment: Is there any message when it exits?

Comment: @EricRenouf None. It just stops

Comment: you create 32400 *(give or take)* `curl` processes with that script? i would look at some kind of sanity check limits - some limit on sockets or background jobs or whatever.

Comment: when it stops, run `echo $?` to get the exit code of whatever died.  That may also be helpful, particularly if it's `curl`.  I might also add `trap "pgrep curl | wc -l > /tmp/curl-process-count" EXIT`; this will drop a count of how many instances of `curl` are running when the script dies into a small file.

Comment: @roaima Ran it with "-x", nothing of interest

Comment: @DopeGhoti `Echo $?` spit out `128`

Comment: @DopeGhoti Where should I call `trap "pgrep curl | wc -l > /tmp/curl-process-count" EXIT` ?

Comment: Put it at the beginning of the script.  What it does is execute the command in quotes when the script terminates for any reason.

Comment: @mikeserv What is the most efficient way to limit the number of curl threads that are created?

Comment: @Yllier - there are *many* ways to narrow it. you need to start with `man curl`. on the first page you'll find info about wildcards and `{brace,patterns}`, so you could do `http://some.address.some:[0-9]/location/image[0-9].jpg` and so on. but you could probably just roll the whole thing into a single `curl` invocation if you put a little time into learning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `wait` instead of `sleep`. `wait` will wait until all background processes finish and then continue, while sleep just delays a second.

See if `wait` works

Comment: Did `wait` work? I'm curious? Please let me know.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have done it. hmm

Comment: unvote this answer. it is wrong